# Bush transplants bought too early

Tags: plant-care, blueberries

[image: I bought some of these starters from a big box store and it says plant them when chance of frost is gone. Since I'm probably still 1 month out how should I best keep them? Should I water them in the plastic bags they are in or leave them dry? Inside or out in cold shed? (Live in South Carolina]

I bought some of these starters from a big box store and it says plant them when chance of frost is gone.  Since I'm probably still 1 month out how should I best keep them?  Should I water them in the plastic bags they are in or leave them dry?  Inside or out in cold shed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the instructions were written by a "writer", not a gardener. Plant them as soon as practical, all plants shown grow where temperatures are below freezing. I am sure I have planted blueberries and raspberries and countless trees, fruit and other wise, before the last frost. I can't remember when I planted grapes and strawberries. The greatest danger is direct sun on the bag when plants are still in them. I always try to plant woody plants when dormant which normally means freezing is still possible. Keep them in a cool place until you are ready to plant; that will be better than in the warm store.

Comment: You're probably correct about the instructions. I'd be willing to bet that the supplier has a single set of planting instructions that it uses for all plants, regardless of cultivar: "Plant after danger of frost at the same level as in the pot. Water well" etc.

Comment: Judging from the picture, the plants are still dormant. The biggest danger is that you keep them somewhere "warm" (i.e. above about 5C or 40F) and they start to grow *before* you have planted them. With no access to water, they will then be badly damaged, or die, very quickly (i.e. in hours, not days.) You can't plant anything if the *soil* is still frozen, because you can't firm frozen soil around the newly planted roots, but air temperatures below zero don't matter.